# Order by and pagination

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-data, querydsl

I have a thousand of records in my database `mysql` and I use pagination to retrieve just 10 results.

When i add a `order by` in my query it slow down but when i omit it the query run very fast.

I know that the problem come from that the query load whole results, sort them and after that it get the 10 records.

I don't use index because the column use for order is a PK and  i think if i'm not wrong in `mysql` a index is created automatically on every primary key

1. Why the index on my PK which is the column I'm ordering.
   not used ?
2. Is there any alternative solution to perform sorting without load all the data ?
3. How to add new inserted data at the first row of tables and not at the end of the table ?

My sql query

```
    select distinct ...... order by appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE desc limit 10
```

and my indexes

```
mysql> show index from appel_offre;
+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| appel_offre |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | ID_APPEL_OFFRE      | A         |       13691 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | appel_offre_ibfk_1 |            1 | ID_APPEL_OFFRE_MERE | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | appel_offre_ibfk_2 |            1 | ID_ACHETEUR         | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | appel_offre_ibfk_3 |            1 | USER_SAISIE         | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | appel_offre_ibfk_4 |            1 | USER_VALIDATION     | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | ao_fk_3            |            1 | TYPE_MARCHE         | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| appel_offre |          1 | ao_fk_5            |            1 | USER_CONTROLE       | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
7 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

no index was chosen in explain cmd:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys                       | key                | key_len | ref
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+-------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------
|  1 | SIMPLE      | appeloffre0_  | ALL    | NULL                                | NULL               | NULL    | NULL
```

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

the problem was from `distinct` when i delete it the query finnaly use the index.

Comment: Have you got an index on your ao.idAppleOffre field?

Comment: i didn't create any index but i think in mysql a index is created automatically on every primary key.

Comment: Try index on the column used for order by. For your second question, there s no 'first' and 'last' rows when inserting.

Comment: the column used for sort is a PK and  i think in mysql a index is created automatically on every primary key. and if there is no first no last why the result i get are sorting from the first row in sert to the last ?

Comment: You get the rows sorted by PK when you use no order by because that's the way MySQL works internally. However, there is no guarantee that this will always stay so, without order by is MySQL free to give you resuts in any possible order as table data are per definition unsorted.

Comment: Could you do explain on your query with and without order by? Could it be that without the joins the query takes the same time with and without order by?

Comment: i update my question and i add the query generated in mysql there is a clause where i think that's why the index on PK didn't get used.

Comment: You should show your full select (not just a fragment), and the results of `describe appel_offre`

Comment: I updated my question with the full select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you already use an index on "USER_VALIDATION", MySQL won't use the ID index instead.

Try rebuilding the USER_VALIDATION index to include the ID too:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX appel_offre_ibfk_4 ON appel_offre (USER_VALIDATION, ID);
```

### Update

Log all Hibernate queries, extract the slow query and use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) in a db console to understand what execution plan MySQL selects for this query. It may be possible for the db to use a FULL TABLE SCAN even when you have an index, because the index is too large to fit into memory. Try giving it a HINT as explained [in this post](http://www.znetdevelopment.com/blogs/2009/10/07/using-use-index-with-hibernatemysql/).

According to MySQL [ORDER BY optimization documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) you should:

To increase ORDER BY speed, check whether you can get MySQL to use indexes rather than an extra sorting phase. If this is not possible, you can try the following strategies:

> • Increase the sort_buffer_size variable value.
>
> • Increase the read_rnd_buffer_size variable value.
>
> • Use less RAM per row by declaring columns only as large as they need
>   to be to hold the values stored in them. For example, CHAR(16) is
>   better than CHAR(200) if values never exceed 16 characters.
>
> • Change the tmpdir system variable to point to a dedicated file
>   system with large amounts of free space. The variable value can list
>   several paths that are used in round-robin fashion; you can use this
>   feature to spread the load across several directories. Paths should be
>   separated by colon characters (“:”) on Unix and semicolon characters
>   (“;”) on Windows, NetWare, and OS/2. The paths should name directories
>   in file systems located on different physical disks, not different
>   partitions on the same disk.

Also make sure DISTINCT doesn't overrule your index. Try removing it and see if it helps.

Comment: it doesn't work and even if i remove the clause `where ao.USER_VALIDATION ` i got the same slow time and no index chosen in explain cmd

Comment: Try with an index hint.

Comment: but it has to detect the index automatically !!

Comment: The engine decides what index to use, if any. You can at most suggest it an index. The execution plan might consider a table scan insisted of an index, like when the index doesn't fit the available memory or it has to access the table anyway.

Comment: I updated my question with full select and i will check your solution tonight.

Comment: the problem was from `distinct` when i delete it the query use the index.

Comment: I also added your solution to this answer, since it was already having some good tips.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add an index to the column by which you are ordering.
2. You can't add rows to the beginning of the table, just like you can't add rows to the end of the table. Database tables are multisets. [Multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) are by definition unordered collections. The notion of a *first element* or a *last element* makes no sense for multisets.

Comment: I don't use index because the column use for order is a PK and i think if i'm not wrong in mysql a index is created automatically on every primary key.

Comment: and if there is no first no last why the result i get are sorting from the first row inserted to the last one ?

Comment: MySQL is not obliged to give you the results sorted from the first row inserted to the last one; and sometimes it doesn't. For example`CREATE TABLE foo (a int) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO foo (a) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
DELETE FROM foo WHERE a=2;
INSERT INTO foo (a) VALUES (4);
SELECT * FROM foo` gives you the results in the order 1, 4, 3.